# PayPal Return Page / Success Page issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am using PayPal minicart on a BuyNow Page.But Problem is that User doesn't redirects back to the return page after completing the traction on PayPal Website.
Although transaction has been successfully  completed but there was no redirect to the return page (  http://XXX.org/BuyerInfo.aspx )

Here is the code

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <fieldset style="float:none">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="X@gmail.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product 1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="6.00" />

                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />




<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://XXX.org/BuyerInfo.aspx" />



                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://XXX.org" />

                <ul id="centerFix" style="text-align:justify"  >
                    <li class="centerf"><strong>Price</strong>: $6.00</li>

                </ul>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
            </fieldset>

        </form>


        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" class="last"> 
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="X@gmail.com"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1"> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View your cart" class="button">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: its not clear from your Q so ill ask, do you pass the return page with your request?

Comment: @Liran I have already added the reurn page  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://XXX.org/BuyerInfo.aspx" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Website Payments Standard only redirects automatically if:

1. 'Auto Return' has been enabled on the PayPal account (via Profile > My selling tools)
2. The buyer is a registered PayPal buyer

If the buyer is not a registered PayPal buyer, they'll have to click the orange "Return to merchant" button.

If you set 'return', this will override whatever value you specify as the return URL in the 'Auto Return' settings.

Can you clarify why you need the buyer to be returned back? There are better, more secure ways to provide you with information when the transaction has been completed, if that's what you need it for.

Comment: Robert Thanks for reply,
I need to direct user to specific  return page because on that page user upload image & fill a form.

My website provides image process services & client need to upload the image if he/she completes a PayPal transaction. So website flow is something like 1st user complete the PayPal transaction After that when client return from PayPal website to a specific success page then he is supposed to fill a form & upload a Image (Its the most Important part of the website).

Also I have already mentioned return URL & I have used a paypal account while testing website.

Thanks

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you rather go with Express Checkout instead. It means working with the PayPal API's, but Express Checkout will *always* redirect a user back to your return URL without delay. This is not the case with Website Payments Standard (as previously mentioned).

Comment: It means that I should not use PayPal minicart? Can you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The minicart uses PayPal Website Payments Standard. Website Payments Standard doesn't always automatically redirect the buyer back to PayPal. Website Payments Standard only redirects the buyer back when he/she uses an existing PayPal account. Guest checkout buyers will need to click a button before being redirected back.

Comment: Usually, this is fine, since most websites are fine with the buyer doing whatever they want as soon as they've completed the transaction. In your case however, the transaction is in the middle of the flow, and the buyer *must* return back to your site. Express Checkout does this.
The only problem is of course, Express Checkout is harder to integrate  than Website Payments Standard.

Comment: Robert I really appreciate  your valuable comments,

but Problem is I can't adopt Express Checkout because there should be a  cart So buyer can buy service in different quantities.
So I am thinking to rearrange Upload & data form page (BuyerInfo.aspx) before the shopping cart page.
So flow would be like 1st user fill the information after that he can buy the product then I don't need the return page.
But how can I implement the security on BuyerInfo Page .Is there any way to check that user x has actually completed the PAYPAL Transaction

Comment: Suppose 10 user has submitted the information (uploaded the image & personal info)  on BuyerInfo Page but Only 4 of them completed the PayPal transaction through BuyNow Page,So How can I validate the transaction of the users or check the Acyual users with completed Transaction.
Flow : BuyerInformation.aspx > BuyNow.aspx > PayPal

Thanks a lot Man..

Comment: You can use PayPal IPN for that; with PayPal IPN, PayPal sends a POST with data to a URL on your server which contains data about all transactions processed for your account. See also my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009274/paypal-post-data-after-successful-payment/6081633#6081633