# Setting auto redirect in payment pro paypal (sandox) after payment

Tags: php, html, redirect, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing the a payment process of paypal.I am using Paypal Website Payment Pro solution.
When the PayPal transaction is complete, PayPal shows this payment successful message:

```
Thanks for your order
Your payment of $XXXX.XX USD is complete.
You're now going back to MYSITE.
If you are not redirected within 10 seconds, click here.
```

I want to skip this page and directly go to my specify page url.

I have followed this instruction as mention in paypal documentation.

1: login in paypal sandbox account

2: i went to profile tab then under Website payment settings then went to Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution and then Settings

there is a auto return option. i enable the auto return radio box and insert the return url .ans then saved it .

but the problem is that it is not auto redirecting .it is showing the same paypal payment successful page with a popup with message "continue or cancel button" if the user pree the cancel button then it will not redirect to my specify url (that i do not want)

I know may be this question is duplicated. but the reason i am asking this question because paypal do changes rapidly .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used PAYPAL php SDK THEN You have to make a success page like"success.php" and in payment.php file you have to set success url of this file(success.php).

Comment: i am not using php sdk. iam using Website Payment Pro solution with html form to submit the payment form. and i have made  a thank-you.php as successful page.

Comment: Ok. Then you have to set cancel url and return url both in your html form like                                                <input type='hidden' name='return_url' value='http://www.abc.com/index.php'>

Comment: yes i am using this html code . but still getting the paypal successful payment page then after my specified page.

Comment: Can you show us your code please? It's near impossible to help in most cases otherwise.

Comment: `<form action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/acquiringweb" method="post"  name="paypal_payment" id="paypal_payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" value="59">
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="LHCKP5XVHW2XC">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://abstest.com./purchase/thank-you.php">`

Comment: try this. it may help you <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://abstest.com./purchase/thank-you.php">

Comment: no its not working . i am still getting the paypal order successful page. i want to skip this page .

Comment: Ok I have found the below information                         Website Payments Standard only redirects automatically if:

    'Auto Return' has been enabled on the PayPal account (via Profile > My selling tools)
    The buyer is a registered PayPal buyer
If the buyer is not a registered PayPal buyer, they'll have to click the orange "Return to merchant" button.
If you set 'return', this will override whatever value you specify as the return URL in the 'Auto Return' settings. for more information read this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692569/paypal-return-page-success-page-issue

Comment: ok thats seem to be helpful. thanks. but i have one more thing to ask is that right now i am using sandbox.if i will use a live account then will it redirection work automatically?

Comment: sandbox is only for test transaction your actual gatway is a live Paypal when you go alive Hope your application's functionality will be working  properly.

Comment: i try it on live but it still showing the same paypal successful order page then my specify page